# Django query, return only if all children's column value is zero

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.1

is there any easy way to do a query where it only returns the parent object (trade) if all of its children's(tradeleg) quantity column has zero value?

e.g. 
return trade_1 if trade_1 has five children and all of its children has "0" value on their quantity field.

e.g.
do not return trade_2 if trade_2 has two children and one of its children has value of "1" on its quantity field.

I have this model:

```
class Trade:
    name = models.CharField(
        default='',
        max_length=50,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    date = models.DateField(
        default=None,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )



class TradeLeg(models.Model):
    trade = models.ForeignKey(
        Trade,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    quantity = models.IntegerField(
        default=0
    )
```

my current query:

```
trade = Trade.objects.filter(tradeleg__quantity = 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current query keeps all `Trade` objects if any of it related `TradeLeg` objects has quantity value 0. Using [`exclude`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exclude) you can exclude all `Trade` objects where any related `TradeLeg` has quantity value other than 0:

```
trade = Trade.objects.exclude(tradeleg__quantity__ne=0)
```

As Amit noted your current query is not valid as `tradeleg` is not a property of a `Trade` object. Either use `tradeleg_set__quantity__ne` or set the [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) property of the ForeignKey.

Answer (score 0):

hi First thing is Trade don't have any reference of TradeLed so the query `trade = Trade.objects.filter(tradeleg__quantity = 0)` is invalid.

For your desired output you can first search the trade by some criteria e.g.

```
trade = Trade.objects.filter(name = <some name>)
```

And use this trade object to filter the TradeLeg objects e.g.

```
tradeleg = TradeLeg.objects.filter(trade = trade, quantity != 0)
if tradeleg:
    return None
else:
    return trade
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the most suitable answer for me. we can use annotate to add virtual column to our parent object. then we can now filter from it.

```
trades = Trade.objects.annotate(total_quantity=Sum('tradeleg__quantity')).filter(total_quantity__lte=0)
```